# NGINX proxy_pass with path prefix removed

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have NGINX proxying requests to several services running on the machine, with location directives as below --

```
location = / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}

location ^~ /index.html {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}

location ^~ /static/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}

location ~* .(config.json|service-worker.js)$ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}
```

All this is working properly, but I have another service to which I want to pass the request path rewritten with the prefix removed. That is, the request to

`https://myserver.com/service` and `https://myserver.com/service/some/path`

should be passed to the service as

`http://localhost:8761` and `http://localhost:8761/some/path`, respectively

Note that for the other services, the full path needs to be passed. I tried the below configuration --

```
location /service/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8761/;
}
```

but this only works for `https://myserver.com/service` and not when there's trailing path.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: Last configuration should work. How did you check?

Comment: @AlexeyTen I tried the url in the browser. It calls `myserver.com/service/some/path`, which fails.

Comment: Show full server config

Comment: And please also show output of `curl -v` for the failing URL.